# Connection to RDS via PHP is very slow some of the time

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an EC2 t2.medium and an RDS MySQL t2.medium and am experiencing something rather frustrating.

First of all, here is my code:

My database class:

```
class Database {

private static $host = 'database-3...us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com';
private static $user = 'admin';
private static $password = '...';

private static $lastConnection = null;

private static $queryCount = 0;

public static function connect(){
    $con = mysqli_init();
    $db = "prod";
    $env = new Environment();
    if($env->isStaging()) $db = "staging";
    //$con->ssl_set(NULL, NULL, "/home/ubuntu/bundled.pem", NULL, NULL);
    $con->real_connect(self::$host, self::$user, self::$password, $db) or die('couldn\'t connect: '.$con->connect_error.":".$con->error);
    self::$lastConnection = $con;
    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8mb4");
    return $con;
}

public static function query($query){
    $start_time = microtime(true);
    $connection = self::connect();
    self::$lastConnection = $connection;
    $result = $connection->query($query) or die($connection->error);
    self::$queryCount++;
    $end_time = microtime(true);
    echo "<br><br>query(".$query.")<br>execution time: ".(($end_time-$start_time)*1000)."ms<br><br>";
    return $result;
}
```

And here is the code I'm executing:

```
$catsQuery = "SELECT * FROM `product_categories` ORDER BY `list_order` ASC";
    
$result = Database::query($catsQuery);
```

Now, most of the time, everything is smooth. This query executes in 10ms or less.

But, some of the time, this happens...

[image]

As you can see, the total time elapsed was over a full second.

Now, through some messing around, I've discovered that what takes the extra time is the connecting to the RDS. The query itself is not the issue, it's just the connection.

I'm on PHP 7.4.

Also, I have eliminated Nginx (as I've bypassed Nginx and gotten the same result) and I've connected directly to the RDS from my EC2 via terminal and there is no delay there ever. So, somehow, the problem is the connection functions PHP is using to connect to the database.

Comment: Your timer wraps both the connection and the query execution. If you separate the two, do you see these longer execution times on the part that's connecting to the database, or the part that's executing the query?

Comment: If I split out the connecting, the execution time stays normal. About 1/2-1ms. It's only when the connecting is accounted for that the total execution time spikes.

Comment: Okay, one possible issue I can think of is a slow DNS server. Have you tried connecting to your RDS via its public IP instead of its host name? Does that make any difference?

Comment: If I try to connect via IP address, the connection hangs and never connects. Any idea what that's about? And yes it is publicly accessible.

Comment: Update: I was able to connect via IP address. Still experiencing the same issue though :/

Comment: The problem is that looking at the above code will not help us or you as the problem is not with the code. Either there is some kind of a setting or a circumstance that's interfering with the connection or there is a problem with php mysqli's implementation of mysql connection functionality. Neither problem can be detected via the above code.

Comment: It sounds like DNS to me too but it might be the DNS on the RDS. I believe MySQL does a host lookup for non-localhost TCP connections. If your db user's access is `*` or an IP I might try turning on `skip_name_resolve` in MySQL to see if that helps.

Comment: @Shadow Is there anything else I can present to help better resolve this? I'll show whatever is needed.

Comment: @cOle2 Yea, I gave that a shot a bit ago but it did not fix it. I'm connecting via IP directly now with skip_name_resolve off and still getting spikes.

Comment: *skip_name_resolve on, not off, sorry.